# Custom Window with Hierarchy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am building a custom window, and I would like to mimic Unity's Hierarchy and add it to my window.

Here is what I have so far, what it doesn't do that I want is to group child and parent object together just like in Unity's editor. Currently it just lists every object in the scene as a list with no sub items. How can I get it to look like Unity's hierarchy view?

```
void OnGUI() {
    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal(); 
    {
        scroll = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scroll, GUILayout.Width(200), GUILayout.Height(500));
        {
            GameObject[] gameObjects = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject[];
            foreach (GameObject go in gameObjects) {
                EditorGUILayout.Foldout(false, go.name);
            }
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
    }
    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
void OnGUI() {
    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    {
        scroll = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scroll, GUILayout.Width(200), GUILayout.Height(500));
        {
            GameObject[] gameObjects = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject[];
            foreach (GameObject go in gameObjects) {
                // Start with game objects without any parents
                if (go.transform.parent == null) {
                    // Show the object and its children
                    ShowObject(go, gameObjects);
                }
            }
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
    }
    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
}

void ShowObject(GameObject parent, GameObject[] gameObjects) {
    // Show entry for parent object
    if (UnityEditor.EditorGUILayout.Foldout(IsEntryOpen(parent), parent.name)) {
        foreach (GameObject go in gameObjects) {
            // Find children of the parent game object
            if (go.transform.parent == parent.transform) {
                ShowObject(go, gameObjects);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you will also need a way to keep track of what object entries are open (implement IsEntryOpen() method). For that you can have a List, and add GameObjects to this list if Foldout() returns true, and remove if it returns false.

You will also want to indent child objects in some way. One way to do this would be to wrap them in `GUILayout.BeginHorizontal()` and `GUILayout.BeginVertical()`, and use `GUILayout.Space()` to indent.

Comment: This works awesome! I added an extra parameter called "Depth" to `showObject` so I know the depth of the item and added space to it.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how `IsEntryOpen` should work... I currently am able to get it to expand, but it doesn't collapse

Comment: `IsEntryOpen()` should return true if object is expanded, and false otherwise. When you click on Foldout GUI item, then `Foldout()` will return true. So you can check for that and mark object as expanded. If object was marked as expanded, but `Foldout()` returns false, then you want to mark object as collapsed. To track what objects were expanded you can have a List<GameObject>, and add all expanded objects there. Then `IsEntryOpen()` would just check if object is in that list.